# Ubuntu apache2 windows10 I want adress server/adress

Tags: virtualbox, windows, apache2, websites

I want some  litlle help thanks.
I have instaled virtualbox on machine. Setup Apache2 and make some test adress.
I want in windows set adress like 192.168.56.212/test.com
and want in windows next adress like 192.168.56.212/nextadress.com

I have now in test.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName 192.168.56.212/test.com
    ServerAlias 192.168.56.212/www.test.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/projects/test.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

but 192.168.56.212/test.com not function.
I setup Nat and so on is correct becouse when I set 192.168.56.212 without /test.com send me apache2 default page
Thanks for help

Comment: Try [this](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-apache#1-overview). It is a walkthrough on setting up virtual hosts on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

A virtualhost of `192.168.56.212/test.com` is *not* valid. Vhosts should be a FQDN, e.g. `example.org`.

To configure multiple names, you would somehow have to configure a working name resolution scheme.

Alternatively you can configure [IP based hosting](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/ip-based.html), where Apache listens to multiple IP's and decides what content to serve based on IP. In that case the ServerName doesn't affect content.